# ESC disconnecting battery while BLDC is rotating protection

Tags: voltage-regulator, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, surge-protection

I was experimenting with *LittleBee-S 30A ESC* and the BLDC did not want to stop so I disconnected the battery while BLDC was rotating and after that the ESC voltage regulator got destroyed. The battery is *5S LiPo battery* and the [BLDC](https://www.bluerobotics.com/store/thrusters/t200-thruster/) can handle max 20V so I think the problem is that the motor generated over 20V when I disconnected the battery.

Is there a way to protect the ESC from disconnection of battery while BLDC is rotating? Will a 20V zener diode over the voltage regulator suffice?

Another option is to swap the voltage regulator with a one that can handle more than 20V.

I think the voltage regulator is [SPX1521](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/146/spx1521-535752.pdf)

> ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS
>
> Input Supply Voltage................................................... -20V to
> +20V

[image]
[image]

Comment: 20V battery??? What battery are you actually using?

Comment: @BruceAbbott 5S LiPo battery. Edited my post.

Comment: You realise your 5S battery will be >21V when fully charged? (>4.2V/cell)

Comment: A link to the product page would help. Googling "LittleBee 30A ESC" gets http://fvt-littlebee.com/ which indicates that it can do up to 6S, i.e. 25V. But what you picture looks nothing like that. Adding a Zener diode won't help you in the slightest as it will just act as a current shunt a burn very rapidly.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I removed the cover and added bullet connector.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I have more of those ESC, that is why i found out that the voltage regulator broke. And the other ESC works fine with 5S LiPo, it's just that I made a mistake and disconnected the battery while motor still running.

Comment: The ESC is rated 4S to 6S but the voltage regulator is max 20V. The voltage regulator can probably handle more than 20V because there is always some factor of safety in ratings. And the battery voltage will drop when load is applied. Still I think the voltage regulator should be rated for 6S instead.

Comment: @Jossi no engineer would design a product rated for a 26V regulator and use a 20V abs-max rated regulator. They would use a 30V rated one or higher.  If you look at images on google of the "LittleBee 30A ESC", they all seem to have DPAK regulators 78D33 regulators. Are you sure you haven't got a cheap clone?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I wrote the name wrong, it's not "LittleBee 30A" The name is "LittleBee-S 30A".

Comment: So yeah, it's basically a badly designed knock-off, it's not surprising it doesn't work. Stick with a 4S battery at most, or buy a properly designed board.

Answer (score 0):

If the regulator really is rated at 20V then you have a problem, because a fully charged 5S Lipo is over 20V. Running electronic components at (or beyond!) their absolute maximum ratings is never a good idea.

Most ESCs will stop after a few seconds if the signal input is removed. This is an important safety feature to prevent the motor from running if the control link fails. Disconnecting the battery is a last resort and shouldn't have to be done, however the circuit should be designed to handle that situation in case it happens by accident.

The motor won't normally produce a higher voltage than the battery supplies, but its windings have inductance which causes a voltage spike whenever the power to them is disconnected (thousands of times per second when the motor is running). Most ESCs have one or two 'bulk' capacitors across the power input to soak up these voltage spikes. However your ESC appears to only have small capacitors which are inadequate, and is relying on the battery to hold the voltage down.

You should wire a large value (eg. 220uF) low ESR electrolytic capacitor across the ESC's power input, either soldered directly onto the PCB or in the power leads.

Comment: There are indeed all sorts of things unsafely wrong with what the poster is describing.  But I don't think the only source of unexpected power is the switching spikes; there's a motor core (and possible a propeller) that is rotating and stores energy; stop driving it and it will induce currents in the coils, which depending on driver configuration could substantially back power the ESC - in more sophisticated systems for examples surface vehicle drives with braking, the battery may actually be charged to absorb this energy (though that introduces its own risks).

Comment: Comparisons to machines with different details are always risky, but as an anecodate, if I move the Y axis table of my 3d printer while the system is unpowered, the current induced in the stepper (which is also a PMDC motor, though with different design goals) gets through to the 12v rail and the LCD backlight briefly comes on.  Part of the reason a power rail can rise so readily in such a case is that the usual larger loads are probably not in a state to draw any power from it - it could well exceed the intended input voltage under such circumstances.

Comment: Sometimes the battery accidentally falls out of an R/C plane in flight, and the pilot is surprised to find he still has control of the model because while the prop is spinning the motor produces enough voltage to power the receiver and servos! However that generated voltage will not be higher than the battery voltage unless the prop is spinning faster than normal (generally impossible because the model cannot go that fast - even in a dive - without power).

Comment: You essentially seem to be saying that the RPM per volt model, ie, Kv, should apply in either direction, and that is probably correct.  But I'm not entirely convinced it reflects the whole situation - would be interesting to couple a pair of well mounted motors with an inch of rubber tubing, run one up as far as can be achieved with a given supply, and measure the open circuit voltage on the leads of its driven twin, then the rails on an unpowered ESC with a scope.  (Actual regenerative brake circuits probably have to be boost converters, but that's a different story)

Answer (score -1):

Linear regulars have a weakness in that they can latch up if their output is higher than their input. This is of special concern in battery powered devices, especially automotive.

If you are lucky, the output capacitance is relatively low so when the input is disconnected this "latch up" just discharges the output capacitance. Over time this will degrade the regulator.

In this specific instance, you have just removed the power to the ESC, the rotor of the BLDC will still have stored energy (\$E = \frac{1}{2}J\omega^2 \$). Its rotation will produce some terminal voltage (\$V = K_e\omega \$).

Input power has been removed but there will still be voltage present on the output of the regulator due to local decoupling, but equally possibly due to the fact there is stored inertial energy that is being rectified back onto your ESC local link (ESC circuit specific)

The simplest solution is to include a reverse protection diode across the regulator to ensure the output never rises more than a diode drop than its input.

[image: schematic]

> **SHORTING THE REGULATOR INPUT**
>
> When using large capacitors at the output of these regulators, a
>   protection diode connected input to output may be required if the
>   input is shorted to ground. Without the protection diode, an input
>   short will cause the input to rapidly approach ground potential, while
>   the output remains near the initial VOUT because of the stored charge
>   in the large output capacitor.
>
> The capacitor will then discharge through a large internal input to
>   output diode and parasitic transistors. If the energy released by the
>   capacitor is large enough, this diode, low current metal and the
>   regulator will be destroyed. The fast diode in Figure 21 will shunt
>   most of the capacitors discharge current around the regulator.
>   Generally no protection diode is required for values of output
>   capacitance ≤ 10 μF.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf

Comment: When the battery is disconnected the input is an open circuit, not a short circuit. In an ESC the regulator only supplies power to the control circuitry (MCU and FET drivers), while the motor is powered directly from the battery. So if the motor generates a voltage it keeps the regulator powered and feedback is not an issue. The problem is almost certainly excessive voltage at Vin, not Vout being higher than Vin.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, all electric motors have a spec called 'Ke'. This 'Ke' describes how many thousands of RPM's you get per Volt applied.

Ke == x KRpm/Volt

So, if you have a motor with a 'Ke' of 1k RPM/volt, and a 20 volt battery, the maximum rpm you can ever reach is Ke*20, or 20kRPM (20000 RPM). This rule applies to all motors and drive circuits, generally speaking.

As you are now familiar, every electric motor is also a generator. The same Ke rule applies, only in reverse. So if you were just spinning at 20kRPM, and disconnect power, the motor is now generating 20k RPM / 1(KRPM/Volt), or 20 Volts.

This implies that if the driver were to simply set all 6 FET's OFF, the motor would generate 20V, and then decay to 0V as friction stops the motor, and the magnets in the rotor no longer induce a current in the windings. This energy 
 generated from the motor flows through the body diodes of the FETs. Usually this energy heats the fets up (due to diode loss), but does not cause damage.

In your scenario, you disconnected Power to the FET driver. We need to carefully examine the behavior of the controller and gate drivers now. What this can do, is cause the fets to turn on and off very quickly, which turns the system into a charge pump. If this happens, it is possible to use the inductance in the motor to generate pulses of energy much higher than your battery voltage. If you have regenerative braking on, and disconnect the battery, where does all this regenerative energy go? As you may find, this energy is converted into high voltage which causes electronics failure.

We can prevent this high voltage generation by safely setting the FETs into the OFF state, and preventing them from turning back on when the battery is disconnected. If, by removing the battery, the regulator browns out, and then recovers from the generated energy of the motor, you must exercise caution so that the FETs do not briefly turn on and off. Otherwise, you may generate high voltages again. Note this condition can oscillate multiple times.

I.e. The battery disconnects. The gate drivers and MCU drain their capacitors and brown out. The brown out briefly causes the FETs to turn on and off. This 'kicks' energy into the motor when the FETs turn on, and then when the turn off, the energy is pumped back to your regulator. This turns the system back on, which then drains the capacitors again, and the cycle repeats until the motor can no longer generate enough energy to 'blink' the system back on.